# Can we run a probabilistic function on ciphertext with Functional Encryption (or Attribute Based Encryption)?

Tags: abe, functional-encryption

In the definition of functional encryption ($FE$):

$FE.Setup(1^k)$ takes as input the security parameter $1^k$ and outputs a master public key $fmpk$ and a master secret key $fmsk$.

$FE.KeyGen(fmsk, f)$ takes as input the master secret key $fmsk$ and a function $f$ and outputs a key $sk_f$.

$FE.Enc(fmpk,x)$ takes as input the master public key $fmpk$ and an input $x$ and outputs a ciphertext $c$.

$FE.Dec(sk_f,c)$ takes as input a key $fsk_f$ and a ciphertext $c$ and outputs a value $f(x)$.

Suppose that Alice runs $FE.Setup(1^k)$ and $FE.KeyGen(fmsk, f)$ where $f$ is a **probabilistic function**. Then she sends $sk_f$ and $fmpk$ to Bob.

Bob runs $FE.Enc(fmk,x)$ and $FE.Dec(sk_f,c)$ to get $f(x)$.

Is this possible? I mean as $f$ is probabilistic, it has to access Bob's randomness pool.

Bob can provide a faked pool. How can one guarantee the privacy of $f$?

Comment: You should look at these papers:
1) [Functional Encryption for Randomized Functionalities](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/729), 2) [On the Relationship between Functional Encryption, Obfuscation, and Fully Homomorphic Encryption](http://web.mit.edu/dwilson/www/papers/abfggtw13.pdf), 3) [Controlled Homomorphic Encryption: Definition and Construction](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/989), 4) [Functional Encryption for Randomized Functionalities in the Private-Key Setting from Minimal Assumptions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/868)

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to prevent Bob from having complete control over the randomness pool.  You could use some form of verified randomness, where your function $f$ checks that the random string is signed before executing.  This would work using, for instance, the NIST randomness beacon.  You could also contain within $f$ a PRNG, so Bob does not need to provide all the randomness but only a seed (which could actually be signed and provided by Alice or another trusted party).  But in the end, there is no way to guarantee statefullness between function calls, so nothing stops Bob from providing the *same* randomness to $f$ every time.  This is a fundamental issue I believe.

Comment: You could instead "contain within $f$ a" PRF, so that Bob can only provide "the _same_ randomness to $f$" on each call with the _same_ input.

Comment: @RickyDemer Is there some measures to prevent Bob from providing the same randomness to $f$ very time? Is there a non-deterministic PRNG or PRF?

Comment: @JianLiu : $\;\;\;$ If $sk_f$ can be quantum, then it might be possible "to prevent Bob from providing the same randomness to $\hspace{.04 in}f$" every time. $\:$ There are non-deterministic PRNGs, but that would just move the problem to preventing "Bob from providing the same" entropy to the PRNG every time. $\:$ Do [invoker-randomizable PRFs](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PS/obf4.pdf#page=25) count as "non-deterministic"? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer That's not a probabilistic function then.  Since the PRF is deterministic based on the input $x$, every execution of $f(x)$ will be identical, even if Bob is completely honest.

Comment: @TravisMayberry : $\:$ That depends on what the PRF takes as input. $\;\;\;\;$